The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage, but explicitly defining removes benefits of intended usage
I'm having some trouble understanding why the type arguments can't be inferred from the usage below.
While the types can clearly be inferred in Build, I'm struggling to understand why (I'm assuming) TResult can't be inferred for Execute.
I've read similar questions, such as this one, and I understand the types are not inferred by constraints. What I can't work out is why the compiler isn't able to infer the return type based on the expression parameter. It can work out the type for new() in Build, but not for TResult in Execute?
I'm ware I could invoke the method with type arguments specified explicitly like so Execute<DemoCommand, DemoArgs, int>(...), but this is usage is undesirable and doesn't do much to answer why it doesn't work.
using System.Linq.Expressions;

// this works
var command = Build((DemoCommand c) => c.Args, new());

TCommand Build<TCommand, TArgs>(Expression<Func<TCommand, TArgs>> propertyExpression, TArgs propertyValue)
{
    var command = Activator.CreateInstance<TCommand>();
    return command;
}

// this doesn't work
var result = Execute((DemoCommand c) => c.Args, new());

TResult Execute<TCommand, TArgs, TResult>(Expression<Func<TCommand, TArgs>> propertyExpression, TArgs propertyValue) where TCommand : Command<TResult>
{
    var command = Build(propertyExpression, propertyValue);
    return command.Result;
}

class Command<T>
{
    public T Result { get; set;}
}
class DemoCommand : Command<int>
{    
    public DemoArgs Args { get; set; }
}
class DemoArgs
{    
}


new() does not take part in the inference of TArgs. TArgs is inferred using the (DemoCommand c) => c.Args argument. TResult cannot be inferred because type inference never takes the return type into account.
